# Z3 / c++ API for quantifiers

Tags: z3

I am using z3 with the C++ API for the example:

context c;

```
sort I = c.int_sort();
sort B = c.bool_sort();

expr x = c.int_const("x");
expr x1 = c.int_const("x1");

func_decl p1 = function("p1", I, B);
func_decl p2 = function("p2", I, B);

solver s(c);

s.add(forall(x, (implies(p1(x), ((p2(x)))))));

s.add(p1(x1));
```

The generated model is:

```
sat
  (define-fun x1 () Int
   0)
  (define-fun p1 ((x!1 Int)) Bool
   true)
  (define-fun p2 ((x!1 Int)) Bool
   true)
```

The imagined to have the model p1(x1) and p2(x1). I tried also with the options:
    p.set("mbqi", true);
    p.set("smt.mbqi.max_iterations", "10000000");
    p.set("auto-config", true);

But, I have the same result. Am I missing something?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z3 produces a correct model, so I'm not exactly sure what the problem is. I can only imagine that there is some confusion about the argument names of the functions.

Per declaration, `p1` is a function that takes an int and returns a Boolean. When Z3 builds an interpretation for this function, it names the first argument `x!1` which has nothing to do with the constant function `x1` (no bang). The model returned states

```
(define-fun x1 () Int
   0)
(define-fun p1 ((x!1 Int)) Bool
   true)
```

which means `x1` is a constant function that always returns zero, i.e., `x1() := 0`. Additionally, `p1` is a function with one argument (called `x!1`) and which returns `true` regardless of the input, i.e., for all `x!1`, `p1(x!1) := true`.

Comment: Thank you.
The model for the same statements without:  
s.add(forall(x, (implies(p1(x), ((p2(x)))))));

is:
(define-fun x1 () Int
  0)
(define-fun p1 ((x!1 Int)) Bool
  (ite (= x!1 0) true
    true))

So, why the previous model is not stating explicitly that (x1 named as 0) give a value true for p1?

Comment: It doesn't state the case x!1=0 because it's not necessary, p1 is true in all cases anyway. Why should it state any such case?

Comment: The model:
(define-fun p1 ((x!1 Int)) Bool (ite (= x!1 0) true true))
means also that it is correct for all the variables but is stating explicitly that is is correct for (x!1 0). It is clear. Thank you.